can tm1637 be used with the built-in i2c of any device
I am using a tm1637 IC not the module to display 4 digit seven segment display, well I am able to make it work, but it uses any 2 digital pins as clk and dio, but I want to make it work with the i2c protocol so that it can be easily configured, can it be possible ?

The TM1637 does not appear to be addressable.  So no, one cannot natively make use of the addressable I2C protocol.  You could use an i2c IO expander chip, or multiplexer, as a middleware chip to enable that type of functionality, at the cost of program complexity and more parts.
